# try-catch doesn't catch an exception thrown during an explicit wait

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

If the MenuNavigationCollapse element does not exist on the page then I want to catch the exception and return another element. Unfortunately my code doesn't get to the catch, it breaks and throws an exception.

```
try
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    var ele = wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(MenuNavigationCollapse)));
    return ele;
}
catch
{
    bAngular = false;
    return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(RMenuNavigationCollapse));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Look closer at the statement that failed, note that it is not wrapped by try/catch.  A catch clause should not throw an exception itself.

Comment: @HansPassant I didn't get what do you mean, can you explain more explicit?

Comment: @JeffC Thanks, I tried to use ExpectedConditions after wait.Until, I worked, thanks a lot. But I still can't understand why this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(numberOfSeconds));
        wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(NoSuchElementException), typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException));
        return wait.Until(d => {
            try
            {
                return d.FindElement(by);
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).